# Elastic beanstalk deployed via cloudformation does not update health check target

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment deployed via CloudFormation.

For now it is a single webserver behind a LoadBalancer, but this will expand with an auto scaling group in the future.

Here are the relevant snippets from my template

```
"BeanstalkEnvironment": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
        "Properties": {
        ...
            "OptionSettings": [
                ...
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application",
                    "OptionName": "Application Healthcheck URL",
                    "Value": "/health"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                    "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
                    "Value": "LoadBalanced"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                    "OptionName": "LoadBalancerType",
                    "Value": "application"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:default",
                    "OptionName": "ListenerEnabled",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:443",
                    "OptionName": "ListenerEnabled",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:443",
                    "OptionName": "Protocol",
                    "Value": "HTTPS"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:443",
                    "OptionName": "SSLCertificateArns",
                    "Value": {"Ref": "Certificate"}
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                    "OptionName": "MinSize",
                    "Value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                    "OptionName": "MaxSize",
                    "Value": "1"
                }
                ...
            ],
            "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.4",
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

The load balancer target group is still using `/` as the path for the health check. Since my web server redirects `/` the health check fails because it does not get the required 200 status code.
If I manually change the target path to be `/health` then the health check works as expected.

What configuration am I missing to be able to set the health check path as part of the CloudFormation template for the environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this setting `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application` is for classic load balancer (CLB).

However, since you are using **ALB** (application load balancer) you should use [aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess).

This option allows you to set (among other things):

- HealthCheckPath: **Path** to which to send HTTP requests for health checks.
- MatcherHTTPCode: A comma-separated list of **HTTP code**(s) that indicate that an instance is healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Right after I posted the question I found the answer myself.

Specifically my problem was that I am using an application loadbalancer.

> The Application Load Balancer health check doesn't use the Elastic Beanstalk health check path. Instead, it uses the specific path configured for each process separately. [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html)

So I need to add a health check for the process that the application loadbalancer is forwarding to.
Luckily both my loadbalancer listeners are using the default process, so if I update the default process health check path, then it will work.

So I changed this OptionsSetting

```
{
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application",
    "OptionName": "Application Healthcheck URL",
    "Value": "/health"
},
```

to be

```
{
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
    "OptionName": "HealthCheckPath",
    "Value": "/health"
},
```

instead. You can find this documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess)